# How do I round up months and days to the nearest month or half month

Tags: excel

I have  a series of time frames in excel that I wish to round up/down to the either the half month or the nearest month.

I have triedto use this code to find the difference between 2 dates in months and days. 
=DATEDIF(G3, H3, "ym") &" months, " &DATEDIF(G3, H3, "md") &" days"

```
Days
2 months, 30 days
2 months, 29 days
1 months, 0 days
3 months, 28 days
1 months, 0 days
3 months, 0 days
3 months, 0 days
6 months, 5 days
4 months, 17 days
5 months, 24 days
6 months, 5 days
5 months, 24 days
5 months, 24 days
5 months, 24 days
2 months, 29 days
5 months, 24 days
3 months, 0 days
4 months, 17 days
4 months, 17 days
3 months, 0 days
4 months, 1 days
0 months, 29 days
1 months, 0 days
0 months, 28 days
0 months, 29 days
3 months, 0 days
0 months, 1 days
```

```
For 1 month 14 days  round up to 1.5  month 
Nearest month or half month


Days
3 months
2 months
1 months
4 months
1 months
3 months
3 months
6 months
4.5 months
6 months
```

Comment: I suggest you use the ROUND function in addition to DATEDIF

Comment: unable to do so

Comment: Please can you let us know what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text were in A1 then

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,2))+IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(A1,11,2)))=14,0.5,IF(VALUE(TRIM(MID(A1,11,2)))>14,1,0))&" Months"
```